# Mutiple value in python qrcode

Tags: python

How I can pass multiple values in qrcode in python? I am using the python qrcode library:

```py
def create_qr(data):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    qr.best_mask_pattern()
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="red", back_color="white")
    img.save('main.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is old but in case anyone else has the same issue; one option is to create a dictionary and put your multiple values in there, convert that to a JSON string, then pass that data to `qr.add_data`.

```py
import json
d = {'name':'mary', 'age': 21}
s = json.dumps(d)
qr.add_data(s)
```

Comment: another way is to use a JsonDF library that makes dynamic Json type that will help you to make any modifications you want in further usage.